# Reading a file in text format and writing it into CSV file in data format using Python

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a folder full of text files with data in CSV format in order to perform some further data analysis. The first line of the text file has headers which are strings separated by `;` and the second line on contains the corresponding data. I am not able to read the file in text format and write it into a CSV file in the data format. My piece of code looks like this but gives me errors about not being able to convert strings into buffer interface.

```
import os
import sys
import csv

# Open a file
full_path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\30695\\My Documents\\Database"
dirs = os.listdir( full_path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
   path = full_path+'\\'+file
   print (file)
   filename = (os.path.splitext(file)[0])
   print (filename)
   txt_file = filename
   csv_file = filename

   in_txt = csv.reader(open(full_path+'\\'+txt_file+'.txt', "rt"), delimiter = ';')
   out_csv = csv.writer(open(full_path+'\\'+csv_file+'.csv', 'wb'))
   out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

I am not sure even if all of it is right or wrong because I want the CSV file also to be separated by a delimiter `;` and all the numbers should be available in data format for calculations.

The input file looks a bit like this:

```
"createTime";"Grid CosPhi";"Grid Current";"Grid Frequency";"Grid kW";"Grid VAr";"Grid Voltage";"Pitch angle 1";"Pitch angle 2";"Pitch angle 3";"Rotor RPM";"Temp.  5    214";"Temp.  6    217";"Temp.  9    227";"Winddirection";"Windspeed"
9/21/14 11:30:01 PM;N/A;N/A;49.963;211688.734;N/A;N/A;-1.06;-1.039;-1.119;19.379;47.167;36;64;N/A;6.319
9/21/14 11:40:01 PM;N/A;N/A;50.002;170096.297;N/A;N/A;-1.003;-0.96;-1.058;19.446;47.182;36.084;63.772;N/A;5.628
9/21/14 11:50:01 PM;N/A;N/A;50.021;175038.734;N/A;N/A;-0.976;-0.961;-1.082;18.805;47;36.223;63.153;N/A;5.577
9/22/14 12:00:01 AM;N/A;N/A;49.964;229942.016;N/A;N/A;-1.047;-1.018;-1.066;18.957;47.125;36.293;63.766;N/A;6.431
9/22/14 12:10:01 AM;N/A;N/A;49.908;200873.844;N/A;N/A;-0.997;-0.985;-1.06;19.229;47.028;36.334;63.962;N/A;6.076
9/22/14 12:20:01 AM;N/A;N/A;49.934;234467.609;N/A;N/A;-1.028;-0.986;-1.001;18.995;47.056;36.401;63.732;N/A;6.067
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run this code under Python 2.6 or 2.7 everything is fine. Python 3.X is more picky about how you open files and what you write to them.

The [2.7 documentation works with binary mode opened](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) files for reading and writing. In 3.4 the opening of files has smartened up and you should just open then for [reading or writing with `r`, resp. `w`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.reader)  (leaving out `t`, or `b'), so the interpreter can do what is needed:

```
in_txt = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(full_path, txt_file+'.txt'), "r"), delimiter = ';')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(os.path.join(full_path, csv_file+'.csv'), 'w'))
```

I would update the whole code somewhat:

```
import os
import sys
import csv

# Open a file
full_path = r"C:\Documents and Settings\30695\My Documents\Database"
dirs = os.listdir( full_path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
    path = os.path.join(full_path, file)
    print (file)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    if ext != '.txt':
        continue
    print (filename)
    txt_file = filename
    csv_file = filename

    in_txt = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(full_path, txt_file+'.txt'), "r"), delimiter = ';')
    out_csv = csv.writer(open(os.path.join(full_path, csv_file+'.csv'), 'w'))
    out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Using raw a raw string for the path so you don't have to escape the backslashes; replacing concatenation of strings to create the full filename by using `os.path.join()` (I had to because I tested this on Linux); and skipping non `.txt` files, because once you create the `.csv` files in the `fullpath` directory, those are going to be spewed out by `listdir()` as well.

What I do to generate YAML files out of CSV files in the `yaml` utility of [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml), is to iterate over the
lines in the input and convert them with process_line:

```
import dateutil.parser # https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil

def process_line(line):
    """convert lines, trying, int, float, date"""
    ret_val = []
    for elem in line:
        try:
            res = int(elem)
            ret_val.append(res)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            res = float(elem)
            ret_val.append(res)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            res = dateutil.parser.parse(elem)
            ret_val.append(res)
            continue
        except TypeError:
            pass
        ret_val.append(elem)
    return ret_val
```

to use that you would need to replace `out_csv.writerows(in_txt)` with something like:

```
for line in in_txt:
    out_csv.writerow(convert_line(line))
```

Comment: It almost worked. I mean, the part that didn't work is my mistake but your code looks pretty clean to me. I am  gonna edit it in my main file. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you please help me what module I should import for 'ext' because I get the NameError: name 'ext' is not defined. Thanks

Comment: @Nikki_Champ, the `ext` is a result of splitting the `file` into `filename` and `ext` by using this line  `filename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)`. You originally threw away the second result from [`splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) (by using `[0]`)

Comment: Oops! Thanks... I have the same code written in a different position in the main file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also did not work. I thought that it was my mistake but its not. The data is still being read in text format and this is not been able to read it as floats and giving the error:ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9/21/14 11:30:01 PM'

Comment: @Nikki_Champ the cvs reading/writing only handles strings. The interpretation of the resulting ".csv" (which only differs in separator from your original) is completely different matter. If you want to have that info convert the .txt to YAML that format "knows" about floats and dates for further processing. Post a new question if CSV is not the output that you want.

Comment: @Nikki_Champ I pulled out some code from the next version of ruamel.yaml, and updated my answer that could help you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the reader is reading in string format, but the writer is trying to write in binary format. What happens if you change your code to this?:

```
out_csv = csv.writer(open(full_path+'\\'+csv_file+'.csv', 'wt'))
```

Comment: I tried that and the writer writes the data in text format which is not usable when I read the CSV file for performing calculations on the data.

Comment: Hmm... well if you want to encode the input string to binary you could try `out_csv.writerows(in_txt.encode('utf-8'))`